# write print driver that supports characterset encoding

Tags: windows, printing, driver

the current windows `Generic / Text Only` print driver doesn't support UTF-8 or windows-1256 encoding, I found [Building a Basic v4 Printer Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/building-a-basic-v4-printer-driver) but nothing mentions how to add/support specific characterset